# The target URL solution deployed to on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution

I want to deploy a solution on SharePoint Online. The SharePoint Online System which I will deploy to contains production environment subsites and testing environment subsites. I want to know how can I choose the target subsites for deployment when I upgrade the solution in SharePoint Online Solution Gallery. Or what is the target URL which the solution deployed to?
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer.

It just will be **stored** in SharePoint Online Solution Gallery if I upload a **new solution**. Otherwise, the features will be upgraded automatically in the sites use the feature in this solution.

If I want to use a new solution, I need to **Activate** the features I wanted in **Manage Site Features**.